# What are the details of the Republican healthcare plan described by Trump in mid-July 2020?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, healthcare, supreme-court, republican-party

Appearing on the 'Fox News Sunday' show on July 19th, giving an interview ([transcript](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/transcript-fox-news-sunday-interview-with-president-trump)) with Chris Wallace, President Trump gave the following response to a question about his administration's actions with respect to Obamacare:

> **WALLACE:** I want to talk to you about Obamacare. Since the pandemic hit, millions of people have lost their jobs and thereby lost their
> health insurance, and almost a half a million have signed up for
> Obamacare. Your administration just announced that you're signing onto
> a lawsuit to overturn Obamacare.
>
> **TRUMP:**  And replace it.
>
> **WALLACE:** Why does it make sense to overturn Obamacare which people now are relying on? Democrats are going to say, "The man who wanted to
> kill Obamacare is going to take away your -- the protection for
> pre-existing conditions."
>
> **TRUMP:**  First of all, we got rid of the individual mandate.
>
> **WALLACE:**  I understand.
>
> **TRUMP:**  Pre-existing conditions will always be taken care of by me and Republicans, 100 percent.
>
> **WALLACE:**  But you've been in office three and a half years, you don't have a plan.
>
> **TRUMP:**  Well, we haven't had. Excuse me. You heard me yesterday. **We're signing a health care plan within two weeks, a full and complete
> health care plan that the Supreme Court decision on DACA gave me the
> right to do.** So we're going to solve -- we're going to sign an
> immigration plan, a health care plan, and various other plans. And
> nobody will have done what I'm doing in the next four weeks. The
> Supreme Court gave the president of the United States powers that
> nobody thought the president had, by approving, by doing what they did
> -- their decision on DACA. And DACA's going to be taken care of also. But we're getting rid of it because we're going to replace it with
> something much better. What we got rid of already, which was most of
> Obamacare, the individual mandate. And that I've already won on. And
> we won also on the Supreme Court. But the decision by the Supreme
> Court on DACA allows me to do things on immigration, on health care,
> on other things that we've never done before. And you're going to find
> it to be a very exciting two weeks.

Two weeks on, have any developments on this healthcare plan taken place, and if details are available, how did the mentioned Supreme Court decision affect the plan?

Comment: The reference to the "[Supreme Court decision on DACA](https://www.axios.com/trump-executive-orders-supreme-court-daca-3d369f16-d9db-4e39-b8a0-946e670797b2.html)" is an oblique nod to the power of the President to implement things by executive order that can't be undone by the next president. Trump is looking to take advantage of this by issuing executive order on health care like his new prescription drug policy: https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2020/07/24/trump-administration-announces-historic-action-lower-drug-prices-americans.html

Comment: Trump has been promising this new ACA replacement repeatedly since he was a candidate, and as far as I am aware the public has never seen anything more detailed than what is listed above.

Comment: @SurpriseDog - I wouldn't say "can't be undone".  I'd say "hard to undo".  The DACA ruling was that the Trump administration didn't go through all the appropriate justifications and process for cancelling DACA, not that it couldn't be done at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I could be missing something but a quick look at [the White House healthcare news feed](https://www.whitehouse.gov/issues/healthcare/) makes me think he was probably bluffing and that nothing significant has happened. I see no bills announced there since July 13th.

So far I also see no mention of anything concrete in the works, but there is a lot of content there so I would encourage you to keep searching if you're so inclined.